# Receiving "core.useBuiltinFSMonitor will be deprecated soon" message while cloning in Git

Tags: windows, git

I recently installed `git version 2.36.0.windows.1` and upon cloning a repo I got the following messages after.

> hint: core.useBuiltinFSMonitor will be deprecated soon; use core.fsmonitor instead

> hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.useCoreFSMonitorConfig false"

Changing the value to `false` does disable the message.

My questions are:

1. What are `core.useBuiltinFSMonitor` and `core.fsmonitor` ?
2. Considering I just installed Git, why isn't the value auto set to false rather than ask the user to do so?

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**
Put my earlier edit as a separate answer down below.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thanks to Chris for the explanation and links to look around.

TL;DR

One can safely use the command `git config --global core.fsmonitor true` to get rid of the message for good.

The answer to the what is in Chris's answer and to why is below.

---

1. Seems like both of them are interconnected and hence they haven't yet disabled one.

> The new FSMonitor feature is controlled by the core.useBuiltinFSMonitor boolean.
> [Link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/3082#issuecomment-919202484)

2. In a recent post they seemed to have *addressed this issue*.

> So I understand that the builtin FS monitor is not actually deprecated, just that the name in the config is going to change, is there, on the current version, any way to use the new name or is the only way to get rid of the message to disable it via the provided command?

> I guess we should clarify by saying core.useBuiltinFSMonitor=true was experimental, please set core.fsmonitor=true` instead.
> [Link](https://issuemode.com/issues/git-for-windows/git/76473399#answer-74435437)

3. **And finnaly, the reason for the prompt:**

> With the feature going upstream into core Git, a decision was made to overload the existing core.fsmonitor setting to take a hook-pathname or a boolean value for the builtin FSMonitor. *However, users may have multiple versions of Git installed on their systems on Windows*. One in the C:/program files/... and hidden versions installed by tools like Visual Studio. And these may be at different revision levels, so one install might only understand the old keyword and one version might understand both (during the transition). **So, auto transitioning it would break whichever one is the older release. So it's safer to just warn the user and let them decide. (And if they know they have multiple versions, they can just set both for now.)**
> [Link](https://issuemode.com/issues/git-for-windows/git/76473399#answer-74435440)

Answer (score 14):

The [release notes for Git for Windows 2.30.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/ReleaseNotes.md#changes-since-git-for-windows-v2302-march-9th-2021) (March, 2021) offer some clues:

> Git for Windows now ships with [an experimental built-in file-system monitor](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/3082), without the need to install Watchman and setting `core.fsmonitor`. It can be turned on by setting both `feature.manyFiles=true` *and* `feature.experimental=true` (or directly, via `core.useBuiltinFSMonitor=true`).

`core.useBuiltinFSMonitor` is not documented on [the Git website](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), even on [an older version where it should exist](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.31.0), but it appears to have been a setting to enable the built-in filesystem monitor for users who want to live on the bleeding edge.

The hints you quote in your question suggest that this feature is now considered stable enough to be the default. Indeed, if we look at [the documentation for `core.fsmonitor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefsmonitor), we see that this is the case¹:

> If set to true, enable the built-in file system monitor daemon for this working directory

(The [older documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.31.0) reveals that this setting did exist prior to this change, but it was used for pointing to an external command to use as a monitor.)

The documentation also explains why we might want a filesystem monitor in the first place, and why a built-in monitor is preferable:

> Like hook-based file system monitors, the built-in file system monitor can speed up Git commands that need to refresh the Git index (e.g. `git status`) in a working directory with many files. The built-in monitor eliminates the need to install and maintain an external third-party tool.

As to why you're getting this warning when you clone, I'm not sure. Did you already have a global `.gitconfig` file in your home directory? Possibly one that your employer ships as part of a default configuration?

---

¹At the time of writing, this feature is documented to be available only on Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 1):

The Short solution - for Windows users - to get rid of the message:

- Edit file C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig
- Add line in section:

  [core]

  fsmonitor = true
- Save file with elevated priv

Comment: You don't need to do this globally with admin privileges. The `git config --global` command in [Angaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72304673/3216427) works in Windows, setting the parameter in your user-global settings instead of the system-global settings like you're suggesting here.

Comment: It is worth noting that in the global config, `useBuiltinFSMonitor = true` is present and as this is depreciated and advised to be replaced with `fsmonitor = true`, then it is worth checking the main system-wide config file and replacing the depreciated `useBuiltinFSMonitor` flaf with the desired `fsmonitor` flag. This is an individual choice, but one that I think is a good idea.